# VPN + Hotspot RPi3 doesnt work

Tags: wifi, vpn

I'm doing a VPN router with Access Point capability, but the router doesn't broadcast network SSID and the network doesn't work at all now. I've realised that when I type `service openvpn stop`, then I have internet back, so the VPN isn't configured properly, but I dont see where I go wrong...

**Basic setup:**
`ifconfig -a` `wlan1` is connected to my router for WiFi internet uplink by using the EDIMAX EW-7811Un adapter, `wlan0` is the Access Point configured with hostapd by using EDIMAX EW-7811Un adapter.

[image]

**Network setup**

> /etc/network/interfaces

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvgpD.jpg]

> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

I have downloaded and installed a custom version of hostapd from here:

```
$ wget https://github.com/jenssegers/RTL8188-hostapd/archive/v1.1.tar.gz $ tar -zxvf v1.1.tar.gz $ cd RTL8188-hostapd-1.1/hostapd $ make $ sudo make install
```

This is my **/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf**:

Then I've installed this:

> $ sudo apt-get install dnsmasq

Now, I have done this, to tell the DHCP server that it controls an IP address range between:

> $ sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.custom.conf

[image]

Now, I have entered to configure the DHCP server to use wlan1 as the device that manages DHCP requests and point the DNS to the Google public DNS servers. Here:

[image]

But in this step, every time I delete or comment out those fields that are assigned by my ISP automatically as seen on picture, they keep coming back after Pi reboot. I don't know why that happens, but saving doesn't work here for some reason.

Now, at this point I the two WiFi adapters are blinking, but I cant see the **wlan0** WAP's network SSID broadcasting where in theory I should, as I think I've done everything..

My IP Tables, please see below:

[image]

As per **eftshift0's** suggestion I attach the `sudo ip link and route` (sorry I couldnt attach more links).

When the system boots, already with all the interfaces running including VPN:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5pQI.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLYyO.jpg
```

After I kill the VPN service with `sudo service openvpn stop`:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElGRW.jpg
```

I am completely lost in what Im doing wrong. I think it's the IP's I have configured wrong, but I can't figure it out myself... Can anyone please help me?

Comment: When you start the vpn, can you show us the output of these commands? Add them to the original question, if you want: - ip link show - ip addr show - ip route show

Comment: even better, run the commands before and after vpn is started

Comment: @Redundant, where are you going with those edits?

Answer (score 1):

The first routing rule when vpn is working is sending traffic to a lot of IPs through the VPN (0.0.0.0/1).

Comment: Sorry, but I am kind of a noob at this, still in the learning process. Is this bad or..? Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: Well.... It's not 'good' or 'bad'. It all depends on what you 'want'. What that rule is saying is that all traffic that is going to this block of addresses will go out THROUGH the VPN link and not the other link that is normally used when the VPN is down: from 0.0.0.0 until 127.255.255.255. and that is A LOT of IPs, actually. A major portion of all addresses that are used normally on internet. Is that's _not_ what you intended, then that's **bad**. Where is that rule set up? I guess you have to look at the VPN configuration files (both nodes if that's the client).

Comment: What exactly is the solution now?

Comment: So I guess I'm going to have to do it from scratch... again until I get it setup. Can you please tell me whether the IPs look okey? Because I was kinda confused, since tutorials showed 192.168...etc. and I use 100.x.x, that's where I kinda lost it a bit.

Comment: that is a good point... I actually didn't notice it. Why are you using 100.x.x.x on the VPN? That is a 'public' segment of IP addresses. There are 3 segments of IP addresses that are used for private networks (like to set up a VPN). https://www.arin.net/knowledge/address_filters.html Can't see the images where I am right now so can't tell you anything else about the IPs.... will check and comment when I can (if you had used text as adviced, I'd be able to comment right away).

Comment: @Ingo Solution? Check vpn configuration and see where that rule is coming from and get rid of it if it wasn't Redundant's intention to have routing traffic that way. Workaround to test: COnnect to the VPN and get rid of that routing rule: **ip route del 0.0.0.0/1**

Comment: Ok... now that's making a little bit of sense. it's not _your_ vpn that you set up. It's a VPN set up by an ISP. That's ok. Then where is the 0.0.0.0/1 routing rule coming from? Because I _guess_ that the only traffic that should go through the VPN is the traffic you want to get to some other portion of your private network... not half the traffic that should go straight to internet (that should go through the plain internet link... I'd guess).

Comment: Sorry, I might sound like a complete moron, because I am a newbie at this. But, the VPN is setup by me, with the use of openvpn protocol downloaded from the privateinternetaccess.com VPN service provider. I have done the del 0.0.0.0/1 and I have internet back with VPN enabled! Althought, every time I delete this roule via the command, after reboot it comes back online.... Please check above in the original post for ip route show again. However, my Wireless Access Point still doesn't work on wlan1, it doesn't broadcast the configured SSID. Do you know what might be the issue?

Comment: Ok... that's one step ahead. You could check the logs for openvpn (either on the file /var/log/syslog or using systemd's journalctl) and see all its output to see where that routing rule is coming from. It could be injected from the openvpn server (I'm assuming you are running the 'client' side of the openvpn connection). About the SSID problem, I don't know what could be going on.

Comment: I have attached the systemlog from today in the original post. I think there's a problem with DHCP as well, or am I wrong?

Comment: this is on /etc/network/interfaces: *iface eth0 inet dhcp*. And it's set to be hotplug, right? So I guess you connected a cable to the interface so it came up and there's no dhcp service on that network. I don't see anything about the server injecting 0.0.0.0/1 on syslog's output. Is there anything about this segment set up on this box's openvpn config file?

Comment: Can you try increasing openvpn's verbosity on its config file?